# How to refresh a HashMap in Java which is already loaded during startup using @PostConstruct annotation

Tags: java-8, hashmap, microservices, spring-webflux

I'm working on a Java application(micro-services) using Spring 5, JDK 1.8, SpringBoot 2.0. I got a helper class where I'm loading a hashmap using the @PostConstruct like below :-

**Helper class:-**

```
private final Map<String, CommonData> empMap = new HashMap<>();

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    loadEmpMap();
}

private void loadEmpMap() {

    List<EmpMap> employees = empRepo.getEmpInfo();
        employees.forEach(p -> empMap
            .put(p.getEmpId(),
                new CommonData(p.getName(), p.getDesignation(), p.getContactNumber())));

}
```

Now during the application startup, @PostConstruct will be called and HashMap will be loaded with data using **JPA Repository**. This HashMap will be available through out this object to use. Now my requirement is to update (auto-refresh) this HashMap with new set of data (ofcourse entity refresh) whenever there is an update/save operation on entity. For this, I have written an Interface like below to Refresh the entity using the EntityManager :-

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;

import java.io.Serializable;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CustomRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
  void refresh(T t);

}


public class CustomRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable>
    extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements CustomRepository<T, ID> {

  private final EntityManager entityManager;

  @Autowired
  public CustomRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation entityInformation,
      EntityManager entityManager) {
    super(entityInformation, entityManager);
    this.entityManager = entityManager;

  }

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public void refresh(T t) {
    entityManager.refresh(t);

  }
}
```

And then extending this custom repository to my application respository like below :-

```
@Repository
public interface EmpRepo extends CustomRepository<Employee, EmpKey> {

}


public final class CommonRepositoryDetails implements EmpRepo {

 private EmpRepo empRepo;

 constructor(){

 }

  XYZMethod(){
    -------
    ---- some line of code for save/update operation using Jpa -----
    -- then trying to refresh the entity as below -----
    
    empRepo.refresh(value);

}
```

I'm not sure whether this will refresh my hashmap again with latest objects from entity to be used or Im missing something here. Please let me know as I want to refresh my HashMap again. Thanks

Comment: It seems like you are looking for some auditing, like `@PrePersist` or `@PreUpdate` etc that spring offers. In any case `HashMap` is not a good option, since multiple threads can work on it - one getting the data, and one inserting it for example...

Answer (score 0):

Since the HashMap belongs to the HelperClass it will be not updated.

I am assuming that you are going to use employee information for the HashMap in the application, because you don't want to  request the database everytime to fetch the records. You can use Spring Cahche mechanism to save the information in the SpringDefault Cache(Concurrent HashMap).
You can use @Cacheable on get methods, it will hit the database when the information is not present in the cache.   @CachePut annotation the update method will update the cache.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial

https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/